# How to use maxResult or q search as parameter of Files.list method in Google drive APIs [python]?

Tags: python-2.7, google-drive-api

from this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

in its python example, how to use maxresult and q search in the code? 
I tried to assign these in param list but it wasn't work correctly.

Comment: You might want to make Internet a better place. You can do that just working on your accpt rate

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

result = drive.files().list(q='"me" in owners', maxResults=10).execute()

This will grab the 1st 10 documents you own.

Comment: q='"me" in owners'-in owners,What does it mean?

Comment: "me" in owners will return only documents which you own. Other search parameters can be found at: https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters